# Is it possible to remove a file from a node package during react-app-rewired build process?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, config, react-app-rewired

I have a react application that users `react-app-rewired build` command. The application needs a file from one of the node package removed.  Is there something I can put in the `config-overrides.js` that will facilitate this?

Comment: Why not just running a script beforehand under `scripts` in `package.json`

Comment: was thinking about that, but I am not entirely sure what `build` command actually does.  If it runs npm install then any script I run before hand to remove the file will just get overwritten.  I will and see if that does the trick.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DennisVash, it worked.